# Replace, not append to, the site's body content in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I had the following idea: my page at example.org serves classic HTML from the server. Besides, EmberJS is loaded, too, and waiting to come into action:

as soon as somebody hits an ember route then, for example `example.org/#/login`, the current  should be replaced by what the view renders for it. From then, the whole app should serve as one-page-app.

Is that a good idea? Anyway, I don't know how to get that started. Overriding View's `appendTo` method or setting the `rootElement` property as in http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/ does not suffice because if that were the body, the view output is just *appended* there…

Comment: Just exclude the classic pages from authentication/authorization checks, I v been learning/working with ember for around 4 months, finished an entire app from head to back without ever resorting to views.

Comment: the login was just an example, could be any arbitrary, actual "ember resource". Just wanted to build a picture of that there's the base page being served, and every subsequent action should be an ember action with the views served as the complete page.

Answer (score 0):

If your entire Ember application requires a user to be logged in, it is valid to have two separate "apps":

1. A regular non single-page application (server-side using rails, PHP or C#) with a sign up and login pages
2. A single-page application (i.e. Ember) send as soon as the user hits the login button in your regular app

You will have 2 index.html pages, one for each application (and it's okay to do that!). The URL of the Ember App could be under `example.org/app/...`. You will need to configure the router of the regular application to server your Ember App for all URLs starting with /app/.

Does that help? :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my project would somehow behave like Facebook, for example: hitting the domain name would serve an introduction and the possibility to log in; but the actual (single page) app would be usable both for logged in and for not-logged-in users (somehow "spectators").
The drawback of having an /app namespace is the not nice-looking URL when sharing; like, example.org/app/profile/john.doe42

But I already agreed "myself" on doing it that way for the time being; still I am open for further suggestions...

Comment: You can have app.example.org pointing to your app too if you want. You can configure your web server to do that easily.